# Memory leak after i take photo from UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, ios7, ios-camera

In my app i start the camera to let the user take a photo :

```
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerControllerSubject = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    imagePickerControllerSubject.delegate = self;

    imagePickerControllerSubject.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerControllerSubject animated:YES];
```

And after the photo is taken, i got a memory leak, you can see my screenshot from Xcode Instrument.

[image]

I isolated the code. I m sure it comes from the camera, not from my app, i left nothing in my didFinishPickingImage function.

```
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
    {

           [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

           return;

    }
```

I use ARC so i don't need to release imagePickerControllerSubject

Here is the screenshot from Xcode Instruments

I use the latest version of ios7

Any idea ?

Thanks

EDIT

I past here the whole code of my view controller. It can't be more simple. And don't forget that i get this memory leak only with iOS 7 and only when the souce type is camera.

```
    #import "FeedbackVC.h"

    @interface FeedbackVC ()

    @end

    @implementation FeedbackVC

    - (IBAction)onClickTakePicture
    {

        NSLog(@"onClickTakePicture");

        imagePickerControllerSubject = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        imagePickerControllerSubject.delegate = self;

        imagePickerControllerSubject.sourceType =               UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerControllerSubject animated:YES];

    }

     - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
     {


         picker.delegate = nil;
         [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
         picker = nil;

         NSLog(@"imagePickerController");

     }

     - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
     {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

        if (self)
        {
            // Custom initialization
            if (self)
            {
              self.navigationItem.title = @"Feedback";

              self.title = @"Feedback";

              self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second"];
            }

        }


        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
       [super viewDidLoad];

    }

     - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
     {
          [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
          // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
     }

     @end
```

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
```

Try:

```
picker.delegate = nil
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
picker = nil;
```

Comment: Did not work :( i still have memory leak, just after the method is called. (and only if the photo has been taken by camera)

Comment: @JeanFrançoisManatane Do you have an overlay for the camera view? If so, it would be helpful if you post some code of that.

Comment: No overlay :( I don't really use the camera, just imagepicker with camera source type.

Comment: This is fixed in 7.0.3